# Phing Property in property file should contain multiple values

Tags: php, phing

As far as I know it is not posssible to have an array of values in a property file.
What would be the best solution to store multiple values in a property?

e.g. part of property file

```
# directory definitions 
# containing e.g. CSS, Javascript, ...
project.dirname_css = css
project.dirname_js = javascript
```

What I want is an array of properties like:

```
# directory definitions 
# containing e.g. CSS, Javascript, ...
project.dirname_css = [css,portal_specific]
project.dirname_js = [javascript,portal_specific]
```

to loop them in the build.xml
Any suggestions how to do this?
I could imagine to do divide values by ; and explode them in the build.xml.
Any better suggestions?

Comment: the property file is an ini file?

Comment: I am not shure whether it is an ini file. It has the structure defined at http://phing.info/docs/guide/current/chapters/appendixes/AppendixF-FileFormats.html#PropertyFileFormat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
project.dirname_css = foo,bar,baz
```

And you will be able to iterate them with the phing forearch task :)

See: http://phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/chapters/appendixes/AppendixB-CoreTasks.html#ForeachTask

Answer (score -1):

Coming across this a few years down the road.  The provided link in Christoph's answer has changed to: https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/ForeachTask.html

Also here is my solution, using Christoph's idea. In my case, I had certain shell script files I needed to make sure where owner/group read/writeable:

```
// In the properties file:
project.perm775files = app/blocker.sh,app/tester.sh

// In the build xml file
<foreach list="${project.perm775files}" delimiter="," param="filepath" target="perm775" />
<target name="perm775">
    <exec command="sudo chmod 775 ${filepath}" />
</target>
```